# Does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I am having trouble with the "add" in the line:

dc.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);

My class statement in Class1.cs should take care of this:

dataclass dc = new dataclass();

Error Code:

```
 'CertainDate.dataclass' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'CertainDate.dataclass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
    public static string GetDate(string mo, string dy, string yr)
    {
        string json = "";
        string date1 = mo.ToString() + "/" + dy.ToString() + "/" + yr.ToString() + " 8:00 AM";
        if (date1.Length > 6)
        {
            List<dataclass> returndata = new List<dataclass>();
            dataclass dc = new dataclass();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jsonobject"].ConnectionString;
            string cmdStr = "SELECT ([idd],[datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3]) FROM [jsondata] WHERE [datetime]=@datetime;";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", date1);
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        dt = ds.Tables[0];
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                dc.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                            }
                            returndata.Add(dc);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            json = serializer.Serialize(returndata);
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Class1.cs

```
public class dataclass
{
    public string idd { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where in your definition of `dataclass` is there an `Add()` method?

Comment: It does not need an Add() in the dataclass class.

Comment: Right... so why are you trying to call that method then if it doesn't exist?

Comment: This is the kind of error where the error text actually describes the problem exactly.

Comment: And apparently you have all forgotten what it was like to learn a new programming language... So perhaps just help the OP instead of ridiculing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to add each datarow retrieved to your returndata list, if this is the case then probably you want this

```
....
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    dataclass dc = new dataclass();
    dc.idd = dr["idd"].ToString();
    dc.datetime = dr["datetime"].ToString();
    dc.col1 = dr["col1"].ToString();
    dc.col2 = dr["col2"].ToString();
    dc.col3 = dr["col3"].ToString();
    returndata.Add(dc);
}
...
```

Of course the error is caused by the fact that you call an inexistant method. The dataclass has no Add method and so there is no way to call that. You could define it and pass the datarow but it is really unnecessary.

You should also be very careful on the evaluation of the returned data. The code above works well if you don't have any null value in your rows. If you have nulls then you should look [DataRow.IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx)  methods

As a side note, if you have a lot of these situations with other classes (meaning tranforming the records loaded in object instances of a specific class) then you could take a look to an ORM that would remove all this code. For example look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be appreciated

Comment: No idea, though might be because `dc.datetime`, in the OP's Q, is a `string`? - stupid if that is the reason.

Comment: @Darren you are right, fooled by the name, no need to convert to a datetime indeed

Comment: Ironically, earlier versions of the code in other questions had that part right.

Answer (score 1):

So `dataclass`, in your question, is a custom class that doesn't have a method called `Add` - this is what your error is saying.

I believe what you're trying to do is add a new instance of `dataclass` to `returndata` - which is a `List<>` and DOES have an `Add` method

So, Change this:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
        dc.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
}
returndata.Add(dc)
```

To this - this is a single liner, which creates an instance of dataclass during the time it's added to `returndata` - you would need to populate the properties of `dataclass` with those from your `col` - we don't know what these are from your question.

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    returndata.Add(new dataclass(){
         idd = ,//whatever column out of col
         datetime = //do the same
     });
}
```

OR, if you're more comfortable (and easier to debug) with creating a `dataclass`, populating it and then adding it to `returndata` then do this:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    dc = new dataclass();
    dc.idd = //whatever is in col, i.e col["idd"] 
    // do the same for all other properties in dc.
}
returndata.Add(dc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `add` method of an instance of dataclass, but you have no definition for `add` method in dataclass.

```
...
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    dc.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]); //Error
}
```